# How to loop in selenium IDE based on part number to select check box

Tags: selenium, ide, selenium-ide

This is my command to select one part number in screen and I'm passing value for part num variable from power automate flow
[image of my selenium ide command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imXlK.png)

this is my xpath -> `

```html
//a[text()='${partnum}']/preceding::input[@name='DHR'][1]
```

I need this to select for multiple part number how can i do that by passing array from flow and how to give command in selenium ide to run like a loop and select part number